# How to code a drop down menu in css?

Tags: html, css, menu, drop-down-menu

I have coded a horizontal navigation as shown below.

[image]

But I am having a hard time trying to code a drop down menu for it.

If someone can help me with coding a plain simple drop down menu below **Rentals** (highlight in the navigation bar in sea blue), I can improve on that.

### Thanks

***Here is my current html file:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"             
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="glossymenu">
    <li class="separator"><a href="#"><b>Reservations</b></a></li>
                       /* Added for the drop down */
                   <ul class="child">
                           <li><a href="#"><b>New Reservation</b></a></li>
                           <li><a href="#"><b>Search Reservation</b></a></li>
                           <li><a href="#"><b>Search Customer</b></a></li>
                           <li><a href="#"><b>Search Vehicle</b></a></li>
                       </ul>
            <li class="separator"><a href="#"><b>Rentals</b></a></li>
    <li class="separator"><a href="#"><b>Tariffs</b></a></li>   

            <li class="separator"><a href="#"><b>Fleet</b></a></li> 
    <li class="separator"><a href="#"><b>Tools</b></a></li> 
    <li class="separator"><a href="#"><b>Reports</b></a></li>
            <li class="separator"><a href="#"><b>System Management</b></a></li>        
    </ul>

</body>
```

***Here is my css code:***

```
.glossymenu{

    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    background: url(../images/menur_bg.gif) repeat-x; 
    height: 36px;
    list-style: none;
    border:solid 1px #CCC;
}

.glossymenu li{

    float:left;
}

.glossymenu li a{

    float: left;
    display: block;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;

}

.glossymenu li a b{

    float: left;
    display:block;
    padding: 0 28px 0 8px; 
}

.glossymenu li a:hover{

    color: #fff;
    background: url(../images/menur_hover_left.gif) no-repeat; 
    background-position: left bottom;;
}

.glossymenu li a:hover b{

    color: #fff; 
    background-image: url(../images/menur_hover_right.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right bottom;
}

.glossymenu li.separator {

    background:url(../images/separator.gif) no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    padding: 0 5px 0 3.5px;
}

   /* Added for the drop down */  
.glossymenu .child {

    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:100px;
}

.glossymenu ul li:hover  {

    visibility:visible;
    z-index:9999; 
}
```

Comment: I actually did, Horizontal drop down menus. Could not get it to work.

Comment: If we leave aside drop down menus being horrible UI controls for websites, then CSS is a horrible tool for creating the interactivity parts of them. You can't put in time delays, allow fuzzy tracking, keyboard access is a no-no and so on. If you must have drop downs, then use JavaScript. Frankly, I'd pay for UDM if I really needed this.

Comment: Please tell us the error or exact problem with what you have tried so far. stackoverflow is a site for helping you figure out the solution to a problem, not for writing your code for you.

Comment: alright its done. I even commented the parts I edited. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like 
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/chrome/index.htm

**Added**:

Some css based menus

http://purecssmenu.com/ -- guess you can generate the css

http://cssmenumaker.com/drop_down_css_menu.php

http://sperling.com/examples/menuh/

Answer (score 0):

in your example i can not see where you set on hover the Second-Level to "display:block".
Here is a simple example for CSS-Dropdown-Menu.

HTML:

```
 <ul class="topLevel">
    <li><a href="#">Car</a>
                <ul class="secondLevel">
                    <li><a href="#">Car1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Car2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Car3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.secondLevel{display:none;}
.topLevel:hover ul{display:block;}
```